# SQLite не находит столбец

Tags: android, sqlite

При нажатии на кнопку ADD, получаю следующий краш:

```
05-17 12:34:22.539 2336-2336/menutest.apps.alexbykov.ru.bd E/SQLiteLog: (1) table contacts has no column named position
05-17 12:34:22.541 2336-2336/menutest.apps.alexbykov.ru.bd E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=1 position=1 mail=1   
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts has no column named position (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(name,position,mail) VALUES (?,?,?)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
at menutest.apps.alexbykov.ru.bd.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:69)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Причина в колонке "position", но в чём именно - не могу понять. Не нашёл ошибок в скрипте создания db.

DBHelper:

```
package menutest.apps.alexbykov.ru.bd;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;




class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {




    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactDB";
    public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_MAIL = "mail";
    public static final String KEY_POSITION = "position";




    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        // конструктор суперкласса
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "
                + TABLE_CONTACTS + " ("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_MAIL + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_POSITION + " TEXT"
                + ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("drop table if exist" +TABLE_CONTACTS);
        onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

Активити-класс:

```
package menutest.apps.alexbykov.ru.bd;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btAdd, btRead, btClear;
    EditText etName, etMail, etPosition;
    DBHelper dbHelper;

    public static final String TAG = "DBLog";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAdd);
        btAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

        btRead = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btRead);
        btRead.setOnClickListener(this);


        btClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btClear);
        btClear.setOnClickListener(this);


        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etMail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMail);
        etPosition = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPosition);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        String name = etName.getText().toString();
        String mail = etMail.getText().toString();
        String position = etPosition.getText().toString();

        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btAdd:

                Log.d(TAG, "--- Insert data in contacts ---");

                contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_NAME, name);
                contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_MAIL, mail);
                contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_POSITION, position);


                //get id
                long rowId = database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, contentValues);
                Log.d(TAG, "--- row insered, ID = " + rowId);
                break;
            case R.id.btRead:

                Log.d(TAG, "--- rows in contacts ---");
                Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, null, null, null, null, null);


                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_ID);
                    int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_NAME);
                    int mailIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_MAIL);
                    int positionIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_POSITION);
                    do {

                        Log.d(TAG, " ID = "
                                + cursor.getInt(idIndex)
                                + " NAME = "
                                + cursor.getString(nameIndex)
                                + " MAIL = "
                                + cursor.getString(mailIndex)
                                + " POSITION = "
                                + cursor.getString(positionIndex)
                        );

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                } else
                    Log.d(TAG, "0 rows");
                cursor.close();
                break;

            case R.id.btClear:

                Log.d(TAG, "---Clear positions---");
                int clearCount = database.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, null);
                Log.d(TAG, "deleted rows count = " + clearCount);
                break;
        }

        dbHelper.close();


    }
}
```

Comment: Бывает если колонку добавил и сбилдил, то её не видит. Попробуйте снести приложение и заново запустить

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Comment: @АндроидАндроид это не просто "бывает", а происходит по вполне определенной причине (см. мой ответ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При любом изменении схемы БД надо увеличивать константу DATABASE_VERSION - она для того и придумана. Без этого метод `onUpgrade` вызван не будет.